# python function compression

Tags: python

I have written this big function to do some formatting in my python code. Would you be able to suggest anyways to make this smaller ?

```
def disfun(String1,String2,String3):
        if String3 == "A" or String3 == "B":
            if String3 == "A":
                pass
            elif String3 == "B":
                print "#"*54

            print "##"," "*48,"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"##"
            print "##"," "*48,"##"
            print "#"*54

        elif String3 == "C":
            print "-"*40
            print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(String2),"--"
            print "-"*40

        elif String3 == 'D':
            String2 = ' * '.join(String2)
            print "#"*54
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"##"
            print "#"*54

        elif String3 == 'E':
            print "*"*54
            print "**",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"**"
            print "**",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"**"
            print "*"*54
```

Comment: I am at a loss why you'd call "String3" something that's clearly the type of banner, and "String2" to something that on one of the branches is `join`ed (so it's in fact a collection). Very cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the first thing is that the names are not at all descriptive. `disfun`? What does that mean? Maybe something like `generateReport`? What are the purposes of `String1` and `String2`? Why does `String2` get printed before `String1`? Why does `String1` not get printed at all when `String3` is `"C"`? Also, python variables tend to begin with a lowercase letter, not an uppercase letter.

As to shortening the function, there's a rule of thumb called DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. If you see the same code written several times, extract it into a function.

Here's a first shot at improving your code:

```
def __printBannerEdge(char, width):
    assert len(char) == 1
    print char * width


def __printBannerContent(char, width, content):
    assert len(char) == 1
    print char * 2, ('{0:^' + str(width - 6) + '}').format(content), char * 2


def __printBanner(char, width, lines):
    __printBannerEdge(char, width)
    for line in lines:
        __printBannerContent(char, width, line)
    __printBannerEdge(char, width)


def generateReport(content, title, selection):
    if selection == "A" or selection == "B":
        if selection == "B":
            __printBannerEdge('#', 54)
        __printBannerContent('#', 54, '')
        __printBannerContent('#', 54, title)
        __printBannerContent('#', 54, content)
        __printBannerContent('#', 54, '')
        __printBannerEdge('#', 54)

    elif selection == "C":
        __printBanner('-', 40, [title])

    elif selection == 'D':
        __printBanner('#', 54, [' * '.join(title), content])

    elif selection == 'E':
        __printBanner('#', 54, [title, content])
```

Some commentary:

- The names I use (`content`, `title`, `selection`) are guess from context. There may be better names possible.
- I'm a little confused as to why the output is so different for each report type. I'm guessing that `selection` is set by user input from a menu of some sort? You should separate the function that parses user input from this function, and have 5 separate functions (eg `generatePartList`).
- One of the oddest thing about the function as written is that sometimes `title` is a single string, and sometimes it seems to be a list of strings (or maybe the `join` statement is meant to "bold" the title name?).
- Better than printing in these functions is to return a string, and let the caller print the string (that makes it easier to write your output to a file instead of standard output, for instance, if you decide later that's something you want to do).